# How could I auto increment a file and have it reset

Tags: perl

I am trying to figure out a way to organize files in a folder with
perl. The basis of my script is sort of simple.  The script reads the
subfolders in the root folder, goes through each folder, and uses a
simple comparison of the first 3 digits in the file name to the 3
digit folder name.  If they do not match, it puts it into the right
place.

My problem is that while looking through the files I sometimes run
into a duplicate order number.  Because the order already exists I
cannot overwrite the original, but the two files cannot exist in the
same place for obvious reasons.  So I had come up with the idea to
append the word `_TEMP` to the end of the file name in order to move
them and they can be renamed later.  The problem I am running into now
is when I already have two duplicates.  I am looking for a way to
allow the TEMP tag to increment by 1 everytime it is used and then
reset to zero each time the loop starts again.  I am just not really
sure where I should implement this idea.

Here is the main routine for the script:

```
foreach my $office (keys %office_names) {

make_junk_folder($office);

# The matches and unmatches come back as array references!
my ($returned_matches, $returned_unmatches) = read_root_folder($office);

foreach my $folder (@$returned_matches) {
    my $returned_files = read_subfolder($office, $folder);

    foreach my $file (@$returned_files) {
        analyze_file($office,$folder,$file);
    }
}

foreach my $folder (@$returned_unmatches) {
    print "$folder\n";
    remove_root_junk($office,$folder);
}
}
```

Here is the subroutine that handles the file moving and renaming:

```
sub analyze_file {

    my $office = shift;
    my $folder = shift;
    my $file = shift;

    my $order_docs_path = $office_names{$office};

    if ($file =~ /^(?<office> (C[AFL]|ME)) (?<folder_num> \d{3})
                   (?<file_num> \d{3}) ([_|\-] \d+)? \. (?<file_ext> pdf)
                   $/xmi) {

        my $file_office = uc($+{office});
        my $folder_num = $+{folder_num};
        my $file_num = $+{file_num};
        my $file_ext = lc($+{file_ext});

        # Change hyphens to a underscore
        $file_num =~ s/\-/_/;

        my $file_name = "$file_office" . "$folder_num" . "$file_num" .
                        "\." . "$file_ext";
        my $temp_name = "$file_office" . "$folder_num" . "$file_num" .
                        "_TEMP" . "\." . "$file_ext";

        if ($folder != $folder_num) {
            # If the folder does not exist create the folder
            if (! -e "$order_docs_path\\$folder_num") {
                system "mkdir $order_docs_path\\$folder_num";
            }

            # Check to see if the file already exists
            if ( -e "$order_docs_path\\$folder_num\\$file_name") {
                # Append the file with a "_TEMP".  These files are
                # missorted pages belonging to a larger document
                rename ("$order_docs_path\\$folder\\$file",
                        "$order_docs_path\\$folder_num\\$temp_name");
            } else {
                # Moves the file to correct place, these are mismatched files
                rename ("$order_docs_path\\$folder\\$file",
                        "$order_docs_path\\$folder_num\\$file_name");
            }
        } else {
            # Files are in the correct place, the file name will be
            # corrected only
            rename ("$order_docs_path\\$folder\\$file",
                    "$order_docs_path\\$folder_num\\$file_name");
        }
    }
}
```

Some example filenames look like this:

CF100145.pdf

CA310244.pdf

CL211745.pdf

CL211745_1.pdf (This denotes a second page, from our document scanner)

ME102103.pdf

Where problems occur is when the same job is changed and rather than putting the file where it should go the person places the updated job information into the current job folder, the directory does not match the first 3 numbers in the file. So later they have to be sorted in order to solve errors, the problem is there are over 500,000 documents in just one office and we got 4 offices.

Comment: I don't think this `[_|\-]` does what you think it does.  It matches an underscore, a pipe, or a hyphen.  I suspect you mean `[_-]` to match an underscore or a hyphen.

Comment: While it is possible to deduce the file names from the regex, it would be much easier if you gave some examples.

Comment: Sure I can give some examples, I was not sure what all was needed.

Comment: @Jim Davis, Good to know, I thought that was the way to do an OR operation in regexp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would change this part:

```
        if ( -e "$order_docs_path\\$folder_num\\$file_name") {
            # Append the file with a "_TEMPn".  These files are
            # missorted pages belonging to a larger document
            my $n = 1;
            while (-e "$order_docs_path\\$folder_num\\$temp_name") {
                $temp_name =~ s/TEMP\d*/TEMP$n/;
                $n++;
            }
            rename ("$order_docs_path\\$folder\\$file",
                    "$order_docs_path\\$folder_num\\$temp_name");
        } # ...
```

Comment: Your idea worked perfectly, even better it gave the solution I needed in order to directly renumber the files instead of having to use the `TEMPn` tag and process those file separately. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You can add _TEMP_OLD_FOLDER_NAME to it.

In this folder was only one file, so no files will be with same new name